# How do i check a checkbox via codes in C++

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Ok so I have two checkboxes in my form1.h Design and my codes in my form1.h is

```
private: System::Void checkBox6_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
private: System::Void checkBox7_CheckedChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e);
```

Now in my form1.cpp, I wish to check or uncheck the checkboxes via code.
I have tried using

```
  checkBox6_CheckedChanged.setChecked(false);
  checkBox7_CheckedChanged.setChecked(false);
```

but it doesn't work.

Please guide me on how do i check them via code.

Comment: What platform? What GUI toolkit?

Comment: I'm coding in C++. under Win32 dll. Using Visual Studios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard warning: This isn't C++ you're writing, it's C++/CLI. C++/CLI is a language from Microsoft intended to allow C# or other .Net languages to interface with unmanaged C++. In that scenario, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. If you're still learning C++, please do not start with C++/CLI. In order to effectively write in C++/CLI, one should already know both C++ and a .Net language (probably C#), and then there's still things to learn about C++/CLI. If you want to learn C++, stick with unmanaged C++. (In Visual Studio, create a "Win32" C++ project.) If you want to learn managed code, then I would use C#. For GUIs, you can use C# with either WinForms or WPF if you want managed code, or C++ with MFC if you want unmanaged.

---

`checkBox6_CheckedChanged` is the name of a method. Your checkbox object is probably named `checkBox6`. The way to set the checked state of a WinForms checkbox isn't `setChecked`, it's the [`Checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx) property.

This is probably what you want:

```
checkBox6->Checked = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and helping me understand!! I will try your method and see how it goes! Thank you so much! Will give a tick if it works!